# XML-Schema with undefined item count

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, schema

I have a little trouble making an XML-Schema.

Here's a little example for what I have in my items.xml

```
<items>    
  <category name="Sample Category #1">
    <category name="Sample Subcategory #1.1">
      <object>
        <name>Sample Inner Object</name>
        <desc>Sample Description</desc>
      <object>
    </category>
    <object>
      <name>Sample Name</name>
      <desc>Sample Description #2</desc>
    <object>
  </category>
  <category name"MyCat #2">
    <object>
      <name>Another Object</name>
      <desc>Another Description</desc>
    <object>
  </category>
</items>
```

Now, as you already have seen, there can be 'infinite' subcategories in a category. They can contain objects but their parents can also contain objects. That describes my problem:
How do I define in a xsd that I want to have -Elements in my first layer but also 'infinite' possibilites in the sub-layers or just objects (containing these two elements).

Is that possible with xsd (I think so but I dont know how) or is my choice to use xml for this kind of 'database' completely wrong?

PS: I want to implement this structure later in C#.

Comment: Unlimited items isn't an issue, (maxOccurs = "unbounded") it's things like can a category element have just an Object element in it. Does it matter what order the object and category elements appear in that will cause problems. The lack of collection elements e.g. (sub)Categories and Objects. Not to mention nesting category inside category. A lose enough xsd to cope with all that will basically end up being you can have anything anywhere which will be pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful?

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType name="categoryType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="category" type="categoryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="object" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="desc" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="items">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="category" type="categoryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```